# How can i capture the adapter name according to unicast address

Tags: winapi

I want to capture the Microsoft virtual adapter name to an Edit box.
I can query the adapters to a Memo, but I want to get only one adapter's name.

```
Name .......... : Local Area Connection* 11
GUID .......... : {55E6FA75-0003-4658-88E4-C63D6714BBC8}
Status ........ : Up
InterfaceType . : Wireless80211
Unicast address : 192.168.137.1/255.255.255.0
Device ........ : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
SharingType ... : ICSSHARINGTYPE_PRIVATE
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo) (XP and earlier) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) (Vista and later) to enumerate all of the local adapters until you find the unicast IP address you are interested in, then you will have access to the associated adapter's name (amongst other info).

Comment: can i get a code example to get the adapter name to an edit box thanks

Comment: @JkRobbin For getting the name you can refer to [official document sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses). For Edit control you can get started from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-a-single-line--edit-control). You need refer to above two samples to implement the one for your case . Feel free to post new question of exact problem you encounter in this process. And it is better to add a programming language tag to your question.